# How to Append Pre-Fetched Data to tbody of DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have some arrays of pre fetched data through ajax calls. I want to append that data arrays to a data table. The code is as follows:-

```
$("#mnGrTblBdy").empty();
    for(var i= 0; i<maingraphdata['datesrange'].length; i++)
       {
           $("#mnGrTblBdy").append('<tr data-child-value="hidden 1">');
           $("#mnGrTblBdy").append("<td class='details-control'></td>");
            $("#mnGrTblBdy").append("<td >" +maingraphdata['datesrange'][i]+ "</td>");
            $("#mnGrTblBdy").append("<td >" +maingraphdata['testorders'][i]+ "</td>");
            $("#mnGrTblBdy").append("<td >" +maingraphdata['cmpltdords'][i]+ "</td>");
            $("#mnGrTblBdy").append("<td >" +maingraphdata['rptsdlvrd'][i]+ "</td>");
            $("#mnGrTblBdy").append("<td >" +maingraphdata['tstsstrtd'][i]+ "</td>");
            $("#mnGrTblBdy").append("<td >" +maingraphdata['tstscmpltd'][i]+ "</td>");

            $("#mnGrTblBdy").append("</tr>");

       } //end for loop

  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var row = table.row(tr);

      if (row.child.isShown()) {
          // This row is already open - close it
          row.child.hide();
          tr.removeClass('shown');
      } else {
          // Open this row
          row.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
          tr.addClass('shown');
      }
  });

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({});
```

But appended rows are shown as a simple table and not a datatable and also it through following error

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Although data is visible but not in a data table rather in a simple html table.

Comment: I think you're trying to work with nested rows, am I right? check [this link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), it might help

Comment: I have already worked on your example and also have implemented that example in some apps. Those work with ajax data calls and then populate data rows. But in my case i have already fetched data through ajax calls and i just want to populate datatable with that arrays of data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use jquery to append `tr` elements like hamburger buns. Either you use string concat to build hamburger style or append in a hierarchical manner.

String concat (you have to mess with the syntax so that maingraphdata is a variable instead of a string, sorry):

```
var row = `<tr data-child-value="hidden 1">');
<td class='details-control'></td>
<td >" +maingraphdata['datesrange'][i]+ "</td>
<td >" +maingraphdata['testorders'][i]+ "</td>
<td >" +maingraphdata['cmpltdords'][i]+ "</td>
<td >" +maingraphdata['rptsdlvrd'][i]+ "</td>
<td >" +maingraphdata['tstsstrtd'][i]+ "</td>
<td >" +maingraphdata['tstscmpltd'][i]+ "</td>
</tr>`

$("#mnGrTblBdy").append(row);
```

Or

Appending properly

```
var $tr = $('<tr data-child-value="hidden 1"></tr>')
$tr.append("<td class='details-control'></td>");
$tr.append("<td >" +maingraphdata['datesrange'][i]+ "</td>");
$tr.append("<td >" +maingraphdata['testorders'][i]+ "</td>");
$tr.append("<td >" +maingraphdata['cmpltdords'][i]+ "</td>");
$tr.append("<td >" +maingraphdata['rptsdlvrd'][i]+ "</td>");
$tr.append("<td >" +maingraphdata['tstsstrtd'][i]+ "</td>");
$tr.append("<td >" +maingraphdata['tstscmpltd'][i]+ "</td>");

$("#mnGrTblBdy").append($tr);
```